# Will .Net call Dispose for me in this case?

Tags: .net, f#, garbage-collection, idisposable

For what I've read on the Internet, you should always call dispose on `IDisposable` objects **as soon as you no longer need them**.

This question is about a particular case where (for me) is obvious that **objects should no longer be needed** and perhaps .Net may call dispose for me.

Case in point:

```
type Foo() =
    let disposable:IDisposable = // create an IDisposable
    ...
```

The question is: As soon as `foo` of type `Foo` becomes unreachable (candidate for garbage collection; no references pointing to it), will `disposable` get disposed?

My guess is that `disposable` won't get disposed as soon as there are no references to `foo`, since there is no reference counting occurring in real time (AFAIK), but *maybe* when `foo` gets garbage collected .Net will dispose `disposable`.

For now, I'm avoiding to create disposables in that location, since it is not completely clear to me who should call dispose and even if .Net called dispose, I don't know how soon it would happen.

Comment: No, the GC does not call `Dispose` on collected objects, the GC is unaware of `IDisposable` entirely.

Comment: You need to implement IDisposable in your class if it owns some disposable resource [see here](http://www.fssnip.net/dM) for simple examples

Comment: Dispose gives you an opportunity to clean up a resource before the garbage collector gets around to destroying the object. There would be no point in the garbage collector calling Dispose, because by that point it's too late to get any benefit from Dispose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's everything you'll need to know about `IDisposable`: [CLR Inside Out:
Digging into IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx)

In short, `Dispose` will not be called by the Garbage Collector, but if the object has a finalizer, the finalizer will be called. All well-designed implementations of `IDisposable` that hold unmanaged resources will have a finalizer that does the same as the `Dispose` method does.

However, if you wait for the Garbage Collector to clear up your memory, you will get non-deterministic behaviour, and it's also likely that your application will use memory in a non-optimal way. **Not disposing of disposable resources is likely to adversely affect performance.**

However, in F#, it's often easy to ensure that objects are automatically disposed of: just use the `use` keyword instead of a `let` binding.

However, that doesn't work in this particular example because Foo is a *class*, which means that `disposable` isn't a *value*, but rather a *field*. That means it doesn't go out of scope until the object itself goes out of scope, but AFAIK, there's no specific language construct to support that (neither is there in C#).

Here's how you can implement the *Dispose idiom* for Foo:

```
open System

type Foo() =
    let disposable:IDisposable = // create an IDisposable
    abstract member Dispose : disposing : bool -> unit
    default this.Dispose disposing =
        if disposing then disposable.Dispose ()
    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose () = 
            this.Dispose true
            GC.SuppressFinalize this
```

The only part that doesn't quite fit into the 'standard' Dispose idiom is that the virtual *Dispose* method (`bool -> unit`) isn't protected, because F# doesn't support that (AFAIK).

Comment: I tried to use the `use` keyboard, but is a syntax error. In fact, that is what inspired me to ask this question.

Comment: @LayGonzález Sorry I was a bit fast on the trigger there; I've now updated my answer.

Comment: Cool. I will experiment with passing the disposables as parameters to the class (if ever needed) and create instead the disposables in something that can go out of scope like async (async allows the `use` keyword). It has being quite illuminating for me this approach so far.

Comment: IMHO the Dispose idiom (ie adding finalizers) is not a good idiom for the 90% (guesstimate) of .NET code that only needs wishes to dispose other .NET objects. As  [Erik](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/21/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-two/) points out an object being finalized can't safely access other objects, therefore the finalizer has nothing to do. In addition adding a finalizer adds object creation overhead (~100x IIRC) and complicates object collection. For the 10% of cases that do deal with unamanged resources the Dispose idiom is the correct one.

Comment: @FuleSnabel The Dispose idiom exists in order to enable subclasses to participate in disposal. AFAICT, there's no better way to achieve that goal. However, if you don't care about that scenario, you can simplify the implementation like in Daws' answer, but then you should **seal** the class.

Comment: @LayGonzález Injecting the disposable object comes with its own set of problems. What if you inject the same disposable object into two different objects? Now you need to do reference counting. It can be done (it's called Dependency Injection, and I wrote a [whole book about it](http://amzn.to/12p90MG), but it isn't a particularly functional approach).

Answer (score 4):

Obvious in this case perhaps but there's no call to `.Dispose` unless you ask for it (replace `let` with `use` for instance).

When the object is GC:ed (which it may never be, non-determinism and all that) if the object has a finalizer then the GC will add the object to the finalizer queue.

The finalizer thread then *might* run the finalizer on the object where the finalizer can free unmanaged resources but *not* managed resources like other .NET objects that implement `IDisposable`. In addition it's hard to free resources with thread-affinity, like Windows handles, in the finalizer as it's the wrong thread.

Finally the object *may* get GC:ed.

So the GC is great (kind of) for pure memory resources, for other resources we use deterministic and explicit resource collection by calling `Dispose` or use `use`.

Eric Lippert recently wrote an interesting [blog](http://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/) on the wonderful world of finalizers which is worth checking out for more details.

Comment: "When everything you know is wrong, part one" I think the author knows me. Thanks and thanks for your answer. Learning C#, F# and .Net at the same time is a little too much.

Answer (score 3):

As previously mentioned, `Dispose` will not be called directly by the Garbage Collector, although the finalizer will be called when `disposable` is garbage collected and will hopefully clean up its resources in a similar way.

Unfortunately, changing `let` to `use` does not solve your problem in this instance since it will yield you a compiler error:

```
type Foo() =    
    use disposable:IDisposable = // create an IDisposable

// error FS0523: 'use' bindings are not permitted in primary constructors
```

Your options here are:

1. Define `disposable` inside a method of `Foo`

   ```
   type Foo() = 
       member this.DoSomething() =
           use disposable:IDisposable = // create an IDisposable
   ```
2. Or, make `Foo` IDisposable and push the responsibility of disposing it to its consumers

   ```
   type Foo() =        
       let disposable:IDisposable = // create an IDisposable

       interface IDisposable with
           member this.Dispose() = disposable.Dispose()

       member this.DoSomething() = ()    

   let bar () =
       use t = new Foo()
       t.DoSomething()
   ```

Comment: Good point, i missed it was a type. Actually i created a F# pr some time ago to autogenerate Dispose methods for types and then modified the compiler to allow use on type members. The F# Community didnt approve though so the PR died....